# Use for loop over list in R to rbind elements if they exist

Tags: r, list, dataframe, for-loop, dplyr

I have a list of c.400 elements, each split into 5 additional components. These are filled with data from excel spreadsheets (after some manipulation in R), but not each component will be filled for every line.

My question is how can I rbind each component in the list, if it exists? For example, if both exist, it would `rbind` `outputs[[1]][[1]]` with `outputs[[2]][[1]]`.

I've tried to produce something for replication below:

x is a list made up of 3 variables, the first is the path (characters, made up of the names of excel spreadsheets I’ve read in), sheet_name (characters, name of each tab in the excel spreadsheets), and data (data.frame, made up of the data in each tab).

```
paths <- list.files(folderpath, pattern = "*.xlsx") # read in all file names with xlsx

x <- tibble::data_frame(path = paths) # make into data frame

x <- dplyr::mutate(x, sheet_name = purrr::map(path, readxl::excel_sheets)) # show number of sheets

x <- tidyr::unnest(x) # each row as a path and sheet name

x <- dplyr::mutate(x, data = purrr::map2(path, sheet_name, ~ readxl::read_excel(.x, .y))) # add data column with data for each tab
```

I then create the following list called ‘outputs’, with 5 variables for each element of the list (which will be filled with Part 1, Part 2, Part 3, Part 4, and Part 5, if they exist in the tab)

```
outputs <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(x)) # make list to put data into

for(i in seq_along(outputs)){
  outputs[[i]] <- vector(mode = "list", length = 5L)
  names(outputs)[[i]] <- paste(x$path[[i]], x$sheet_name[[i]], sep = "___")
}
```

I then run a for loop to populate the relevant element in each loop.

I'd like to add a for loop that first checks whether `outputs[[k]][[1]]` exists, where `k = length(outputs)`, and if it does, to add all existing `outputs[[k]][[1]]` to a new dataframe and rbind it into one big dataframe.

My thoughts on this are that it would look something like the below, but I'm not too sure how it would work:

```
#create part1 dataframe
for (k in 1:length(outputs)[[k]][[1]] {
if(exists(outputs[[k]][[1]]
part1 <- rbind(part1, [[k]][[1]]
}
```

In addition, I'd also like to add two columns for each existing `outputs[[k]][[1]]`, with the path and `sheet_name` from the outputs list.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Can you provide some sample of the data (for example using `dput`) and the expected form of the output?

Comment: I've added some detail, hope it helps!

Comment: Do you have a list of data.frames?. If it is the case maybe you can use `bind_rows(list_of_dataframes, .id = "sheet_name")`